# How to lock user from posting data on asp web api when some process is running

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I have a saas web accouting application hosted on azure. At the end of the day, the user will have to do book closing. When this process run, i want to allow user to view data but not modify it, because it might interfere with the process. Any recommendation or pointer on how to do this in web api? This is a multi tenant app, so when a user run this process, only that user data is locked, not the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

Unless each user's data is store separately, it might not make sense here to use actual thread locking.

However, in your code where you would modify data, you could check for a variable that you set in your book closing code. Whenever you start book closing, set it to true for that userID. When you are done, set it back to false.

(You may also want to after a certain amount of time check to make sure it went back to false, in case there is an error don't want to permanently lock out the user)

That way it doesn't effect your ability to view the data or lock any threads, but when it comes time to write anything you have a check that can gracefully return a "Please wait until the book closing process is finished" error message.